# AudioKit and AVAssetWriter conflict ? No Audio on first record only

Tags: ios, audio, audio-recording, avassetwriter, audiokit

**Context:**
I am using AudioKit and GPUImage2 in my app.
I have a first screen (Record) to get a preview and record the camera.
I have a second screen (Play) to play the recorded movie and to process the audio (with AudioKit)

on Record screen, GPUImage2 uses a simple AVAssetWriter to capture video and audio. The audio is recorded with this trivial code:

```
guard (assetWriterAudioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaDatav) else {
     return
}

if (!assetWriterAudioInput.append(sampleBuffer)) {
     print("Trouble appending audio sample buffer")
} else {
}
```

This code is called as it should and assetWriterAudioInput is not nil.

On Play screen, I launch two players, a muted AVPlayer for video and a AKAudioPlayer for audio (to be processed) with the same file as source.

Two notes which if removed do not affect my issue.

- During record, I play a music on top of the user voice, with AKAudioPlayer.
- During the play, I put the music on a mixer with recorded voice (so 2 AKAudioPlayer into 1 output AKMixer)

During record, I play a music on top of the user voice, with AKAudioPlayer.
NB: during the play, I put the music on a mixer with recorded voice (so 2 AKAudioPlayer into 1 output AKMixer)

My issue is:

**When I record the first time, I get only the video on Play screen, no audio has been recorded. The mixer is working good as I hear the music I add in it.**

**When I start again (back action to Record screen), I record normally and on Play screen, everything is functional -> video plays, voice+music is played.**

Can someone help me to resolve this?

If it can help, the AudioSessionCategory I use is *PlaybackCategory*, it never changes during the app lifecycle, so same on first and next records. It only changes from Ambient to Playback at app launch because I let the speakers play with physical mute button active.

Comment: Have you found solution for this?